# how to set printer quality to "best" mode?

Tags: mfc, winapi

if i set printer quality  = DMRES_HIGH 
then also it printing in normal mode.

Comment: Hi, please go through your questions and accept some answers, this way you encourage people to give you more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bit of a daft question in return, but given [the MSDN description on DEVMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452943.aspx), are you sure your driver/printer supports the setting in this manner?

> A printer driver supports only those
>   member of the DEVMODE structure that
>   are appropriate for the printer
>   technology.

Comment: I am sure that the printer supports the "Best mode", is set log also i takes (-4) as  ptinter qaulity also.

Comment: And the printer prints 'high quality' correctly when you print from a regular application? (If you use the print dialog)?

Comment: Please any body tell the solution for this question. Why printer is not setting for the "Bset" mode.